# Changing the text color in a widget using "R.color.red"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to change the text color in my widget depending on an `if`. So I have my remoteViews sorted and I can change the actual text with no problem but when I try and change the color using `R.color.red` it just shows up as black.

```
RemoteViews remoteViewSmall = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.smallwidgetlayout);
remoteViewSmall.setTextColor(R.id.widgetdatasmall, R.color.red);
```

Is this an incorrect way of retrieving the color "red" I have set in my `colors.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Color.RED`. Would that be what you are looking for?

Or are you trying to re-define the colors?

Try this if that is the case:

`remoteViewSmall.setTextColor(R.id.widgetdatasmall, getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to use my own defined ones, I want a lighter shade of red

Comment: @MattHarris: Try my other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of layout re use.

Set the value on every possible condition. That means set the value to red if you have to and otherwise set it to black.